# How to replace google signature key in an already existing application with the key of another application

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-signing

Right now I have two applications that have different application signing keys, I would like to replace the key in one application so that it is the same as in the second application. How to do it?

Comment: You can't use the same key with different applications. You also can't change an already signed applications key.

Comment: @HB. You can use the same keys for different applications, Google allows you to do this when you first publish the application, but I did not do it

Answer (score 0):

You can contact Google Play Console Support and ask them to change the key for you.

In the play console click the help button at the top > Scroll down to heed more help and click "Contact Us" > Type in you need help with a Keystore Reset > Click "next step" > Click "Upload key reset request" > Click "Contact Google Play Developer Support" > Then choose a contact method to contact them to reset it for you.